# react-select select multiple items in the drop-down list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to select multiple items from the drop down list? I know that it is possible to set `isMulti` on `Select`. However the list disappears as soon as firs item is selected, where I wanted the list to be open and select multiples values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closeMenuOnSelect` from `react-select` to accomplish this.

```
<Select
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    options={options}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

You can see the a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0xp0pqo20)